# Ubuntu 18.04 - No Wifi networks found

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 18.04 Dual booting with Windows 10 on my HP-EliteBook-745-G2, and for some reason, I cannot seem to find WiFi networks through my WiFi adapter, but Ethernet works (however, Ethernet stops working properly if I shut my screen down, and go back into my laptop, forcing me to restart my laptop to use Ethernet).

What I have done that didn't work:

- Uninstalled Kernels and reinstalled.
- Tried using `rtlwifi.new` as a fix.
- Tried connecting through a hidden network, with different networks in different places.
- Reinstalled Ubuntu.
- `sudo service network-manager restart`

So I thought I would create a new post to get a different perspective here.

Side note: WiFi works perfectly on the Windows side of things, these problems persist only on my Ubuntu boot.

The output of `lshw -C network` gives:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for nathan: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0f0
       version: 0e
       serial: 30:8d:99:bf:09:ab
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.0.0.167 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:39 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d5804000-d5804fff memory:d5800000-d5803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 03
       serial: 28:c2:dd:8f:85:ec
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:38 memory:d0a00000-d0a07fff memory:d0800000-d09fffff
```

Edit: Just for the people using edits to correct my grammar, 'I'd' is the same as 'I would'.

Another edit: Ran `rfkill list all` and here's the results:

```
    $ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Then ran : `dmesg | grep wl` to produce:

```
$ dmesg | grep wl
[    0.000000] DMI: Hewlett-Packard HP EliteBook 745 G2/221C, BIOS M84 Ver. 01.07 03/10/2015
[    6.918774] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    6.918782] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    6.951608] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    7.123725] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43b1 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[    7.330784] wl 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   10.672629] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   10.791775] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
```

[Full diagnostics](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VCbx6FVMcf/)

```
 $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
```

Edit again

```
    :~$ sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl
[    0.000000] DMI: Hewlett-Packard HP EliteBook 745 G2/221C, BIOS M84 Ver. 01.07 03/10/2015
[    7.004949] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.004958] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    7.011342] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    7.888998] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43b1 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[    7.923740] wl 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   11.818773] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   11.937130] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[ 2546.180968] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[ 2546.291784] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep wl` and also, does this produce any output? `sudo iwlist wlo1 scan` I don't need to see the result; just tell me if it errors out or if it sees networks.

Comment: @chili555 No clues in the log, Output added to post for 'dmesg | grep wl', and no, the other command doesn't see any networks.

Comment: @Kulfy However, he already has the correct driver *bcmwl-kernel-source* installed.

Comment: My favorite kind of problem: everything is just perfect except it doesn't actually work! Let's look at the full diagnostic report from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Please give us the paste link.

Comment: @chili555 I've added the full diagnostic into the question. Thanks

Comment: May we see: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` The diagnostics suggest that it is missing altogether!

Comment: @chili555 output added in the post

Comment: Please see my partial answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I had several times problems with Ubuntu 16.04 and restart of network manager always solved the issue.

So please try

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I should have included this in my post, this was another thing that I had attempted to begin with, didn't solve anything :c

Answer (score 0):

This will be a partial answer until we track down the exact issue. I will edit the answer to provide further steps as we progress.

First, the conf file for a Realtek driver isn't needed; please remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

Second, your `/etc/network/interfaces` file is faulty. Please amend it:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Amend the file to read:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

**EDIT**: We notice this error in your paste:

> ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get :

A search reveals many complaints involving your exact 14e4:43b1 device and only one solution: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=236084&start=20

I suggest that you try the same:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep wl
```

Comment: So far no improvement.

Comment: May we see: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version` We hope it is 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4.

Comment: I can confirm it is: 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4

Comment: I have just seen this edit now. Did broadcom install steps, but didn't fix the issue. 'dmesg | grep w1' shows the same as it did before except '[ 10.585199] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready' repeats 8 times.

Comment: I hope you meant: `dmesg | grep wl` not w1.  wL not w-one Do you confirm that the `ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get :` is still present?

Comment: That error is not present

Comment: If the error is gone, we see no reason that it doesn't see networks and connect. Please run: `sudo iwlist scan` Does it see your network? What is the result of: `dmesg | grep wlp`

Comment: iwlist has no scan results, and grep wlp doesn't do anything

Comment: How about: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` ?

Comment: Displayed it in my next edit

Comment: The results look very good. Does it scan now? `sudo iwlist scan` Your full diagnostics report is missing. Please generate and post a new one.

Comment: Still getting no scan results, I've edited the original diagnostic link with a new one.